# Spark streaming jobs are failing after running for few days

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am facing this issue, my spark streaming jobs keeps on failing after running for few days with below error:

```
AM Container for appattempt_1610108774021_0354_000001 exited with exitCode: -104
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Container [pid=31537,containerID=container_1610108774021_0354_01_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 5.8 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used; 8.0 GB of 27.3 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1610108774021_0354_01_000001 :
|- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
|- 31742 31537 31537 31537 (java) 1583676 58530 8499392512 1507368 /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java -server -Xmx5078m -
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

spark submit:

```
spark-submit --name DWH-CDC-commonJob --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10 --conf  spark.eventLog.enabled=false --conf spark.sql.caseSensitive=true --conf spark.driver.memory=5078M --class com.aos.Loader --jars file:////home/hadoop/lib/* --executor-memory 5000M  --conf "spark.alert.duration=4" --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --num-executors 3 --files /home/hadoop/log4j.properties,/home/hadoop/application.conf --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" streams_2.11-1.0.jar application.conf
```

Have tried increasing the spark.executor.memoryOverhead but it fails after few days, I want to understand how we can arrive to number  where it can run without any interruptions. Or is there any other configuration that I am missing.
Spark 2.4 version
aws EMR: 5.23
scala :2.11.12
Two data nodes( vCPU 4, 16 GB ram each).

Comment: It's seems quite straightforward, it seems your job has some memory leak and/or data, memory goes beyond what was allowed to, then aws/emr kills the container

Comment: @gtosto have been monitoring in RM UI-> Storage tab, DFs are getting cleared from memory for every micro batch. Any place  I can look into for memory leak.

Comment: could also be differences in sizes of batch of data. The data incoming rate is quite uniform? How far the memory demand of a micro batch execution is from the 5.5 Gb ?
I know this doen's help much, but it's hard to say where or how

Comment: I had a similar problem and as a workaround we resorted to periodic restart of the stream job.

Answer (score 0):

NM is killing your job, check the node hdfs disk usage. Are you shuffling crazy amount of data? Also check if you're bombarding hdfs with container logs.
Also check if this is part of dynamic allocation or static.